# How to show value of each bar in react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, charts, bar-chart, react-chartjs

I have a question about bar chart in react-chartjs-2. I made a bar chart and pie chart using react-chartjs-2 in my application.

I could show the value of pie chart using a [plugin](https://github.com/emn178/Chart.PieceLabel.js) calls Chart.PieceLabel.js. But I couldn't find a plugin for a bar chart. **I want to show the value of each bar as same as pie chart.**

Is it possible to value of each bar in a bar chart?

Current view is like this. In pie chart, the value of each slice appears.

[image]

Here is my code

```
export default class Categories extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        slideOpen : false,
        piData : piData
      }

this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
this.update = this.update.bind(this);
this.doParentToggle = this.doParentToggle.bind(this);
}

doParentToggle(){


this.setState({
    piData : piData
  })
  this.update();
  }

handleClick(){
    this.setState({
        slideOpen : !this.state.slideOpen
    })
    }

update() {
  var piData;
  this.setState({
    piData : piData
  })
}    

  componentDidMount() {
    let ctx = this.refs.chart.chart_instance.chart.ctx;
    console.log(this.refs.chart.chart_instance.chart.ctx); // returns a Chart.js instance reference
    this.refs.chart.chart_instance.chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
                if(dataset.type === 'bar'){
                    const dataArray = dataset.data;
                    dataset._meta[0].data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                        ctx.fillText(dataArray[index], bar._view.x, bar._view.y);
                    });
                };
            })
  }

render(){


 const CategoriesPanel = this.state.slideOpen? "slideOpen" : "";
 const { length } = this.props


  var totalData = piData + piData2 + piData3 + piData4 + piData5;

   let newpiData =  function() {
   return parseFloat((piData /  totalData ) * 100 ).toFixed(2) };

   let newpiData2 =  function() {
   return parseFloat((piData2 /  totalData ) * 100).toFixed(2) };

   let newpiData3 =  function() {
   return  parseFloat((piData3 /  totalData ) * 100).toFixed(2) };

   let newpiData4 =  function() {
   return parseFloat((piData4 /  totalData ) * 100).toFixed(2) };

   let newpiData5 =  function() {
   return parseFloat((piData5 /  totalData ) * 100).toFixed(2) };

  const data = {
  datasets: [{
    data: [ newpiData() , newpiData2(), newpiData3(), newpiData4(), newpiData5()],
    backgroundColor: [
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'purple',
    'green'
    ],
    borderColor: [ 
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'purple',
    'green'
    ]
  }]};

  var pieOptions = {
      pieceLabel: {
     render: function (args) {
              return args.value + '%';
            },
     fontSize: 40,
     fontColor: '#fff'
   }
  };

  const bardata = {
  labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
  datasets: [
   {
  backgroundColor: [
    'orange',
    'blue',
    'red',
    'purple',
    'green'
    ],
  borderColor: 'black',
  borderWidth: 3,
  hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
  hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
  data: [ piData , piData, piData , piData , piData ]
  }
  ]
  };

  return(
<div>
<div id="chart" className={CategoriesPanel}>
<div style={{"display" : "flex"}}>
<Pie style={{"fontSize" : "20px" }} data={data} options={pieOptions}/>
<HorizontalBar
      ref='chart'
      data={bardata}
      width={100}
      height={50}
      options={{
        maintainAspectRatio: false
      }}
    />
  </div>
 </div>
<div className="categoriesSlide" onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.slideOpen? <img src={Arrowup} alt="arrowup" className="arrowup" /> : <img src={Arrowdown} alt="arrowdown" className="arrowdown"/>}</div>
 <div className="clear">
 <List parentToggle={this.doParentToggle} />
 <ListSecond parentToggle={this.doParentToggle} />
 <ListThird parentToggle={this.doParentToggle} />
 <ListFourth parentToggle={this.doParentToggle} />
 <ListFifth parentToggle={this.doParentToggle} />

 </div>
 </div>
    )
}
}
```

I appreciate your kind help, thank you for taking time to read my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a horizontal bar using react-chartjs-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451884/make-a-horizontal-bar-using-react-chartjs-2)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To show the data value on each bar, you can use a plugin called : [**chartjs-plugin-datalabels**](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/)

**install** (via npm)

```
npm install chartjs-plugin-datalabels --save
```

**import** (in component)

```
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
```

**options** (to show value)

```
plugins: {
   datalabels: {
      display: true,
      color: 'white'
   }
}
```

<sup>* add this inside chart options</sup>

see all the available options of datalables plugin [here](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/options.html).

Comment: Sorry for late response. You are the chart.js expert. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? Value show up only when data is updated. By default,  no data shown up. Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Not sure what you're experiencing.. perhaps post a new question with more details.

Comment: thanks. I posted another question. It would be great if I can get your insight.

Comment: Thanks! Took me forever to find the correct way to declare this!

Comment: btw, if you are using `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` v1.x, make sure you register the plugins per [this instruction](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration)

Comment: I followed your instruction but couldn't able to resolve the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68046847/adding-data-labels-inside-charts-in-reactjs-is-not-working

Answer (score 5):

If you are using it for a React App, then import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels' in your main index.js file. This will automatically add datalabels to all your charts. In order to remove the unwanted datalabels from specific charts, add the following to the respective options object:

```
options = { plugins: { datalabels: { display: false }}}
```

Answer (score 2):

First install chartjs-plugin-datalabels

```
npm install chartjs-plugin-datalabels --save
```

Then import it and Chart.js

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';
```

Then register it

```
const MyFunction = () => {
   Chart.plugins.register(ChartDataLabels);
...
}
```

Finally use it in options

```
 options: {
  plugins: {
    datalabels: {
      color: '#36A2EB'
    }
  }
}
```

You can find this information in the [website](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration)